# Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, top-7

While it might be a touch early, I think everybody visiting can see this site is already populated with a lot of questions.

[Chris W. Rea](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-w-rea) started the original Stackexchange site, BasicallyMoney.com site and he and [Zephyr](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/19/zephyr) would be the people responsible for creating what you see today.

Per the blog post: [**Moderator Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

**This is the basic structure of a Moderator nomination thread:**

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.
- Include the bullet points (from above) to show what we are looking for.

Comment: It is *not* too early to start these conversations. Please see: [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/). I updated this question with the guidelines.

Comment: So when do we close the nomination/voting process and pick a new moderator?

Answer (score 15):

### [Chris W. Rea](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-w-rea)

Chris made the original community, and his fair minded and consistent leadership kept the site clean and relevant.

- EDIT: I (Chris) accept the nomination.  Thanks for your nomination and kind words.

Answer (score 11):

### [Zephyr](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/19/zephyr)

Zephyr was the other prominent moderator on the original stackexchange site, so whatever he did worked well and vote to keep it going.

**Edit:** Thanks for the nomination - I (Zephyr) look forward to helping with the new beta!

Answer (score 7):

### [C. Ross](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/users/312/c-ross)

I've been an active participant since the BasicallyMoney days, and I also actively participated in the [area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721?phase=definition) for this site.  I've been on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16487/c-ross) for over a year, and I am also an active participant on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16487/c-ross).  I've also  setup the [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131/basically-money) and participated with Alex and Ganesh (others please join us!).

I live in the South East US and I follow the financial world fairly closely.  I listen to both Dave Ramsey and Clark Howard on a regular basis and can speak to their philosophies.  I also have a firm understanding of basic economics and accounting.  Professionally I'm a programmer analyst for the finance department of a large US company.

As for my style I tend to be a little aggressive in closing questions.  I hope that the users of Money will give me the opportunity to work with community as a moderator.

Answer (score 5):

### [Alex B](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/815/alex-b)

I live in Colorado in the US and saw Chris W. Rea's [appeal](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/moderator-election-shouldnt-our-moderators-come-from-a-variety-of-countries-n) for moderator nominations from other countries.  I've been active during the money private beta, participating on the [money site](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/815/alex-b), the [meta.money site](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/users/815/alex-b), [asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60042/does-it-make-sense-for-stack-exchange-1-0-sites-that-are-active-to-go-through-pri) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60221/how-are-bounty-questions-migrated-from-se-1-0-to-se-2-0) at meta.stackoverflow.com related to the money private beta, and participating in the Basically Money [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131/basically-money) room.

[I joined StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6180/alex-b) during the private beta and have a long history of Questions and Answers there as well where my reputation is over 5K.

All of which leaves quite a bit of information about myself out there for you to peruse when considering my self-nomination.

Answer (score 4):

### [MrChrister](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/11/revisions)

He's been active in Meta, and was a good user (and mod?) on the old site.

**EDIT**  Thank you very highly for the nomination, but I must respectfully decline as I don't really feel like I am the best person for the job.

Comment: Shucks, but I respect the decision.  I'm gonna leave my +1 here though in case you ever change your mind :-)

Answer (score 3):

### [Ganesh Sittampalam](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/366/ganesh-sittampalam)

In answer to the [appeal for moderators from other countries](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/moderator-election-shouldnt-our-moderators-come-from-a-variety-of-countries-n), I'll put myself forward as a British one.

I was active on Basically Money prior to the SE2.0 beta and have asked and answered questions during the private and public betas, as well as being active on the meta site. I've also got a reasonable reputation on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96982/ganesh-sittampalam).

Comment: +1 I have always liked Ganesh's writing style.  I feel he is a good communicator.

Comment: Also, is this *you*? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesh_Sittampalam

Comment: Yes, that's me. Not that it's at all relevant to this election :-)

Comment: Gets my vote anyway.

Answer (score 3):

### [George](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/868/george-marian) [Marian](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/users/868/george-marian)

1. I believe that my rep score is reasonably high for someone who's passion for business and finance was rekindled by his participation in this very site and is relatively new to the entire SO family of sites and their offspring.
2. While I am relatively new to the entire [SO/SE community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377225/george-marian), I've [branched out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377225?tab=accounts#tab-top) quickly as appropriate for my interests and sustainable by my bandwidth.  (Ok, maybe I've stretched myself a bit thin, as demonstrated by my many 101's.  That said, I'm not here to rack up points.)
3. I certainly believe that I lead by example in my questions, answers and even comments.
   I regularly leave comments suggesting improvements for questions and take part in discussions related to the answers/questions.  (I don't have as much of a history of that on here as I do on SO.  Ironically, my highest scoring answers can be found here on this site where I have been active for a shorter period of time.)
4. I *somewhat* regret that my branching out and presence on http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com has put a serious drag on my quest for 2k rep on SO.  (I so want the ability to fix/apply formatting, especially on a programming related Q&A site.)
   I believe that my answers demonstrate my commitment to considered responses to any question on which I have an opinion.
   I also spend a fair amount of time reading questions which I cannot really answer, simply because I am interested in knowing what is happening on the site.

Bonus points for:

5. I have only recently begun to check out the meta for money, as I was not involved in Basically Money and so I wanted to get familiar with the community and site.
6. FWIW, I did tweet about the site to all of 44 followers, 105 Facebook friends and my whopping 67 connections on LinkedIn. :)
7. The interest to promote, grow and improve the community is certainly there.  My interest in the community is one of the reasons I joined the public beta of the new chat system the very day it was announced.  As far as the promotion part of the equation, I am still working on how to do that without being an annoying ass spamming his friends like an out of control salesman.

Comment: +1 for @George.  He always seems to be answering questions at about the same time I do and his are always more eloquently written.

Comment: @mpenrow Thank you for the kind words.  I'm glad that my efforts have not gone unnoticed. :)