# A Call for Moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'd like to **shake things up a little** on this site and add a couple of new moderators to our existing staff. If you're the type of high-energy person that can juice up the community and help drive the on-going improvements desperately needed on this site…

… then I'd love to hear from you.

So, I am turning to the community and issuing a call to arms. **This community needs people to lead it!** Moderation is about accepting edits and handling flags, yes, but it's also about serving as a role model to the community — mentoring others to be productive contributors to this site while making those tough decision to keep this site on track to becoming a lasting and valuable resource; one that *makes the internet a better place!*

Typically the "pro tem" program starts with a call to nominate moderator candidates. But this time around, I really want to encourage **self-nominations only.**

If you are interested, please post your interest in the answers below. The nomination thread linked below has some good replies to the question —

[**Who should the moderators be?**](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/who-should-our-beta-moderators-be)

You can read about the appointment process in [**Moderator Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), and learn what it takes to be an effective moderator in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Aarthi. Looking forward to the expanded team!

Comment: You linked the Workplace nomination thread, the money one is http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/11/moderator-election

Comment: Any criteria for candidates?

Comment: @BenBrocka [status-bydesign] -- your thread was filled with people giving excellent reasoning for why they should be chosen. :)

Comment: @C.Ross Nothing concrete; a willingness to lead and a desire to help improve and build this site so it can graduate!

Comment: What happened to this proposal, what's the next logical step? Are we appointing new moderators or we are waiting for some more nominations ...

Comment: @Dheer I'll be reviewing the results this week and appointing an additional mod by the end of this week. Thank you for the reminder! :)

Comment: Hi everyone -- so I fell sick and haven't been able to plow through to this just yet, but yes, this is still going to happen. I haven't forgot about you, and I apologize for the delay. I appreciate your patience!

Comment: <ping!> Feeling better, I hope?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Yes! This is currently on hold while we do a writeup of the eval results and respond to some of the meta posts we've been seeing here in the last few weeks. :) It's not off my radar by *any* means!

Comment: @FeralOink Hello, Feral Oink -- I apologize for any discomfiture and unhappiness I have caused you. I'm more than happy to discuss this with you at length in the PFM chatroom, or via email, whichever you would prefer.

Answer (score 8):

Well I will throw my hat in this time.

https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91/mrchrister and https://money.stackexchange.com/users/91/mrchrister

When we think about it being three years, I have been around along as most people.  While I am super interested in these topics, I also know that some of the more technical things still are over my head and I learn stuff here most days.

I would like to encourage a friendly attitude on the site, recently I think the tone has become a bit harsh and judgmental.  I also understand that emotions don't come through in words very easily, so as a moderator I see the job mostly about making everybody feel welcome and encouraging participation, especially new questions!

Comment: I second the nomination.

Comment: I thirded the nomination.  MrChrister is always tactful and respectful.  He would be an excellent choice.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer : Where is your nomination?  I think MrChrister, you, duffbeer, and mbhunter would round out the moderator list nicely.

Comment: @muro, I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm flat out. A day job, and 4 web sites I'm trying to promote. Getting tougher to manage my time. Again, thanks. I know mbhunter, a great choice, and younger, maybe he'll throw his hat in the ring.

Answer (score 7):

I'll throw my hat in the ring.  I haven't been as active on Money lately, but I've been involve on Money since the early days, and I'm definitely [experienced in the world of StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/9022/c-ross?tab=accounts), as I already mod the RPG site.  I'm not a professional finance expert but I spend a lot of time reading about and listening to financial advice.  Mostly I'm just exciting about seeing Money *succeed*.  That means graduating, and contributing positively to the internet at large.

As a moderator I would love to help clarify what's on topic, and enforce the standards of politeness that are required here.  I would also love to build up the community, and help get great questions pushed out on social media.

<sub>Note: I volunteered [last time](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/67/312) but due to a missed communication it didn't work out.</sub>

Comment: I have always found C. Ross to be pleasant and representative of the type of voice to have on this site.  If moderation is a people job, C. Ross would be good.

Comment: The skill required to be a mod is not identical to that of a good responder. Kinda how refs in baseball weren't required to be all star players. I third your nomination.